# what sorting algorithm has time complexity Θ(N)?

Tags: math, time, time-complexity

what sorting algorithm has time complexity Θ(N)?

Θ does this symbol mean worst time complexity

linear search time complexity is Θ(N) but it isn't a sorting algorithm though...

Comment: No sorting algorithm has `O(N)` complexity. The best is `O(NLogN)`.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

Comment: @Enigmativity that is obviously not true ... histogram based sorts are `O(N)` they are also called `counting` or `bucket` sort in english. However they are not usable for arbitrary data. It has some restrictions on dynamic range of sorted data vs. memory needed for histogram.

Comment: Θ(N) (Big Theta of N) means the time complexity class of the algorithm is exactly N. O(N) (Big O of N) would mean the complexity is N or better, Ω(N) would mean the complexity is N or worse. [Big O wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations)

Answer (score 1):

If the numbers in the array are non-negative and small enough so that an array can be declared which size is the maximum number of the array then you can use counting sort.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort

Comment: what if negative numbers are used?

Comment: In the case of negative numbers, you can find the minimum numbers from the array, let's assume it's ```-x```, then add ```x``` to all the numbers. Use counting sort to sort the array. Add ```-x``` to all the numbers